# can cache be applied for storing important informations?

Tags: php, caching

I am creating an app which is to be hosted in an multi server environment . My frond end is php and backend is java. i am calling everything using rest client. so  i want to reduce the number of api calls. For that i need to store the relevent information on client side once it is called once. i dont want to call same api twice(like user profile info). so what is the best option for this ?

Earlier i thought of using session, but i hope that wont work out for multi server enviornment. I dont have a database in frontend.

so can i use cache for this ? can cache be used to store user related data?
is cache reliable for this use?

Comment: apc or memcache aren't persistent (ie userdata won't survive a restart), redis will (and has the added bonus of supporting replication across distributed cache servers)... but caching using any of these is commonly used by many systems

Comment: "cache", without further context, is just a generic term. It's like asking if you should use "storage".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using REST you can cache the API calls themself by using **a cached HTTP-Proxy** to connect to the REST Server.

Comment: +1.  A lot of people use Nginx for the proxy server.